# Doctrine : Use dash in field alias

Tags: sql, symfony, syntax, doctrine-orm

This MySql instruction is valid `select id "object-id" from object`

How can I do the same with Doctrine? All my tests returned syntax errors.

```
$result = $this->em->createQuery(
                   'SELECT o.id \'object-id\'
                    FROM MyBundle:Object o')
               ->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [this issue's answer](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5140):

> This doesn't work because the persister uses the column-name for the AS part of the query. We won't fix this programatically, this is rather a restriction of Doctrine 2.
>
> For this reason i have updated the documentation to state that non a-zA-Z0-9_ chars should not be used (even quoted) as columns.

So you simply should not use a dash here.

Comment: OK, that is make sense. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1):

[Consulting the context-free grammar](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#ebnf) your syntax is not supported in DQL.

`SelectClause` definition:

```
SelectClause ::= "SELECT" ["DISTINCT"] SelectExpression {"," SelectExpression}*
```

`SelectExpression` definition (see `AliasResultVariable` at end):

```
SelectExpression ::= (IdentificationVariable | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration | PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression | NewObjectExpression) [["AS"] ["HIDDEN"] AliasResultVariable]
```

`AliasResultVariable` definition:

```
/* Alias ResultVariable declaration (the "total" of "COUNT(*) AS total") */
AliasResultVariable = identifier
```

`identifier` definition:

```
must match [a-z_][a-z0-9_]*
```

So the correct syntax in your case should be:

```
$result = $this->em
    ->createQuery('SELECT o.id AS object_id FROM MyBundle:Object o')
    ->getArrayResult();
```